# How to change a global variable and have a previous function see it?

Tags: bash

To avoid the XY problem, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
terminate=0
terminated=0

monitor_something() {
  while [ "$terminate" -eq 0 ]; do
    echo "Doing stuff"
    sleep 1
  done
  terminated=1
}

monitor_something &
show_interface

terminate=1
while [ "$terminated" -eq 0 ]; do sleep 0.2; done
```

The idea is to run a loop in the background that takes care of some things (for example restart an erroneous service or whatever) and then show the user interface. When the user interface exits, I need to wait for `monitor_something` to properly exit without being in the middle of something.

The problem is that `monitor_something` doesn't see the change in `terminate`. Is this a problem because `&` is creating a subshell? Here's a simple script for testing purposes:

```
#! /bin/bash

var=10

func() {
  while true; do
    echo "var: $var"
    sleep 1
  done
}

func &

echo "Init"
sleep 2
echo "Changing var to 5"
var=5
sleep 2
echo "Done"

kill -TERM %1
```

My question is, how can I make that background function see the change in the global variable and respond to it? In general, what can I use to do what I'm trying to do? Could I for example tell `monitor_something` to ignore the `TERM` signal but set a variable instead and exit when that variable becomes 1?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. They're no longer the same variable.

Comment: I was afraid so. How would you address the problem I'm trying to solve?

Comment: I would use `wait` in order to wait for the child to finish.

Comment: and a signal to tell the child to terminate, rather than a variable.

Comment: @thatotherguy, except `kill` would terminate `monitor_something` at any unspecified moment, rather than letting it choose when to terminate (loop condition).

Comment: how about create a global variable and export it whenever the variable is changed ?? something like: `VAR=1; some_func(){ echo $VAR;  }; some_func; export VAR=2; some_func`

Comment: @sa77, I'm not calling `some_func` again. It's the same `some_func` from the background that needs to respond to the change.

Comment: @Shahbaz not true. Signals are there to be handled (via `trap`), and immediate exit is just the overridable default for a few.

Comment: @thatotherguy, obviously I had not known about `trap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
monitor_something() {
  stop=0
  trap 'stop=1' TERM
  while [ $stop -eq 0 ]; do
    echo "Doing stuff"
    sleep 1
  done
}

monitor_something & MONITOR_PID=$!
show_interface

kill $MONITOR_PID
wait $MONITOR_PID
```

The call to `kill` replaces the `terminate` variable, and the call to `wait` replaces the `terminated` variable.

Comment: `kill` could terminate `monitor_something` at any point. `monitor_something` in reality manages insertion and removal of a kernel module as well as `kill -TERM`ing and restarting a process in the background (hence, _monitor_). That's why I'm looking for a way to let `monitor_something` choose when to terminate (at the boundary of the `while` loop), rather than terminating at an unspecified moment.

Comment: In that case, you can set up a signal handler inside the process to set a variable to exit the loop. See my edit; I haven't tested it yet, but it (or something similar) should work.

Comment: perfect. The last sentence in my question was just asking for this. I'll test this and let you know. (P.S. I should have known better to use `wait`, but the `trap` command was what I was really missing).